Elasticsearch ID 'filter' in Query-DSL
I am trying to get an ID filter running in Elasticsearch, so that only a specific subset of documents is searched (or at least returned) with other filters.
(This is saved as a Mustache template)
Right now it looks like:
script: {
lang: 'mustache',
source: {
  from : "{{from}}{{^from}}0{{/from}}",
  size : "{{size}}{{^size}}10{{/size}}",
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: [
        {
          "ids": {
            "values": "{{objectIds}}{{^objectIds}} [] {{/objectIds}}"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
options: { content_type: 'application/json;charset=utf-8' }
}

I also replaced "must" with "filter" but still didn't received any results.
My Ids are very likly correct as requesting the endpoint
local-elastic/local-app/_doc/MY_ID

returns the correct document with "_id" set to my ids.
I also changed my mapping to
"mappings": {
        "dynamic": "true",
        "date_detection": true,
        "numeric_detection": false,
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }

to index my ids (as id was previously of type text, and indexing was set to false).
I also tried to use
"must": {
  "terms": {
    "_id" : ["fancy", "ids"]
  }
}

which runs into an error telling me [terms] cannot use field [_id]. (The docs point out that instead of this query, my other approach would be the same)
Right now, i have absolutely no clue why my request is not working.

Can you please provide sample data? Aslo, do you want to filter based on ES _id field or you have your own id field in data.

The problem is not the query but the Mustache script.
As any normal programming language would insert an array like ["val", "val2"], JavaScript inserts "val,val2" instead.
Therefor, the array is lost and unfortunately not even a correct error message of Elasticsearch is thrown (something like: Array expected, but string given).
To solve this problem i just had to wrap my array into a Json representation.
